# Hyuuga and Uchiha clan family roots?

Tags: naruto

The Uchiha clan is descended from the Hyuuga, right? So then why is the Hyuuga clan not seen during the founding of the Konoha Village? How did the Uchiha awaken Sharingan, when originally they had Byakugan? How did they come into changing their name? Would an Uchiha be able to awaken Byakugan? On that note, what would happen if a person were to obtain byakugan, eternal mangekyou sharingan, and rinnegan?

EDIT (4/2/14):
So now Kaguya is shown to have Byakugan. It is evidence that Uchiha, Senju, and Hyuuga are indeed related. But how does the Hyuuga then come about?

Comment: According to the series, eternal mangekyou and Rinnegan are progressive forms i.e One comes after another. Hence you can't have both at once.

Comment: well now that Kaguya has shown to have the kaguya clans kekkei genkei. i wonder if hamura could have it as well hmmmm we should out find soon, unless kishi is planning on not giving him any background like he did many time's with other clans and people. i mean yamcha on dragon ball z has a background and he's a side character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Uchiha are not a descendant clan of the Hyuuga. That was speculated by Kakashi in the very early stages of the series.

Much more information was revealed afterwards (***SPOILER!* Hover to view**):

> Both the Uchiha and the Senju (The clan of the First Hokage) are descendants of the Sage of Six Paths, who created ninjutsu and had the powers of a god.

Also

> A Rinnegan is the next stage of evolution after the Mangekyo Sharingan, so you can't really use them both at once on the same eye. The Byakugan has nothing to do with it and is a completely separate technique.

Comment: how about transplanting both, sharingan (ex. Kakashi) and bykugan (ex. Ao)? I would love to hear your speculations ;)

Comment: @Vogel612: Speculation is not in the scope of this site. You're welcome to join us in [chat] though :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha But Kaguya, the Rabbit Goddess, is shown to be wielding Byakugan...

Comment: @Alex-sama: My speculation based on the latest chapter is that the Sage of Six Paths is the ancestor of the Uchiha and Senju clans, while his brother (Gamamaru?) was the ancestor of the Hyuuga clan.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Exactly my thoughts. His brother, not Gamamaru. Gamamaru is the prophet toad sage. His brother is not named, but I have further questions towards his brother which I will write in another post.

Comment: True enough. TIL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to say that this is fact but here is a theory. Kaguya possesses two bloodline traits the byakugan and another sharingan/rinnegan trait. Upon having her two sons she could have passed the two traits down separately (seeing that we have not seen the sage's brother this is possible). This would mean that the sage obtained his mothers sharingan/rinnegan eye which manifested as the rinnegan without the sharingan tomoe.

Upon the sage having his two sons he passed down his visual ability, albeit a weakened version (the sharingan), to his eldest and his physical energy to his youngest. It is, as we know, that only when senju and Uchiha blood mix do you acquire the rinnegan.

Pretty much what this theory states is that it is possible that the hyuuga clan originated from the sage's brother while the rinnegan and sharingan originated from the sage himself. This would mean that the byakugan and sharingan exist as two separate dojutsu from two separate bloodlines.

Answer (score 1):

It is theorized that the Uchiha and Hyuga clans are related. Kyuga was the first being to have all 3 dojutsu but it is unclear how she is related to the Hyuga clan. Some people believe that the Hyuga clan also came from Indra just like Uchiha did. For all we know Hyuga can be descended from Haruma as we don't know much about him or Hyuga origins. I made a Otsutsuki Bloodline tree just click on the hyperlink to see. [Otsutsuki Bloodline](http://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1TKzaEVwAVcmqedAr6P4SER_5pl6Dh7eR6-hr7-FQxO8/edit)

Answer (score 1):

As evidenced by *The Last: Naruto the Movie*, the Hyūga and Uchiha share a common ancestor: Kaguya Ōtsutsuki‎‎. The Uchiha are descended from the Sage of Six Paths and the Hyuga are descended from the sage's brother, Hamura Ōtsutsuki. Given that the divergence happened before either clan was founded, it would be inaccurate to say that the Uchiha are descended from the Hyūga.

> The evidence that the Hyūga are descended from Hamura is both stated and implied by dialogue in the movie from Hinata; the ghost of Hamura; and Toneri Ōtsutsuki, a descendent of Hamura. Furthermore, Toneri uses Byakugan, as did the rest of his clan.

Answer (score 0):

hamura his byakugan so its easy to say that he is indeed the hyuga ancestor. so this means that the hyuga are cousins to the uchiha, senju and uzumaki

Comment: Did you mean for [your other answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/11601/1908) to be part of this one? If so, you can [edit] this one to include that information and delete the other one. (While you're at it, you might want to do some edits for capitalization and so forth.)